# How much and to whom should I give Zakah?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, zakat

I would like to know how much amount of zakat should be given and to whom it can be given. I am an employee at a company and my salary is always at the end of the month.  Can I give goods as zakat instead of money ? Can I give it to relatives or should it be specifically for certain people?

For example, if I have 100 rupees, I can divide it among 2 people or 10 people. Which one is more recommended ? Giving less money to many people or giving more money to few people ?

I have heard that its 2.5% of the yearly savings. What if I don't have any yearly savings? What should I do in this case ?

Comment: It's quite hard to determine Zakat on paper currencies since they have no value and in present times they're not backed by any commodity.
Zakat can only be paid on things that have an intrinsic value like silver, gold, wheat, barley, dates and salt.

Comment: http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/17114

Answer (score 2):

Alaikumu Ssalam

You have mistaken Khums with Zakat.

Khums is obligatory on the following seven things:

> 1)Profit or gain from earning.
>
> 2)Minerals.
>
> 3)Treasure trove.
>
> 4)Amalgamation of Halal wealth with Haraam.
>
> 5)Gems obtained from the sea diving.
>
> 6)Spoils of war.
>
> 7)As commonly held, a land which a zimmi (a non-Muslim living under
>   the protection of Islamic Government) purchases from a Muslim.

(reference: **http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2285/**)

As you can see just we are commonly obligated to take care of the first one (Profit or gain from earning.)

3.There are many rules regarding how and when one has to pay khums on Profit or gain from earning but the first and most general rule is that

> if a person earns by means of trade, industry or any other ways
>   of earning, like, if he earns some money by offering prayers and
>   fasting on behalf of a dead person, and if it exceeds the annual
>   expenses for maintaining himself and his family, he should pay Khums
>   (i.e. 1/5) from the surplus.

For the detailed rules please visit: **http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2286/**

> 4.Khums should be divided into two parts. One part is Sehme Sadaat, it
>   should be given to a Sayyid who is poor, or orphan, or who has become
>   stranded without money during his journey. The second part is Sehme
>   Imam (A.S.), and during the present time it should be given to a
>   Mujtahid, who fulfils all conditions or be spend in the ways allowed
>   by that Mojtahid. Regarding the first part khums can be spent, for
>   such purposes by the permission of that Mujtahid. As an obligatory
>   precaution, that Mujtahid must be Aalam, and well versed in public
>   affairs.
>
> 5.If the wife of a person is a Sayyidah, he should not, as an obligatory precaution, give Khums to her for meeting her own expenses.

For more detailed rules please visit: **http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2293/**

Comment: Copy-paste answers are against the policy of this site. Relevant [meta] discussion: meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/953.

Comment: as you can see, the texts had to be edited to fit the appropriate answer so it's not considered a Copy-paste unless you want to be too disciplined.

Comment: Just that it doesn't meet the site policy. You're welcome to share your idea in the [meta] discussion linked above.

Comment: please determine quotes and try to write your answer from your own words.